# Meta keys won't add using wp_insert_post

Tags: post-meta, wp-insert-post

I have the following code, I am attempting to insert a new post with the 2 meta fields attached, the post is being inserted but the meta isn't there.

Can't seem to spot anything wrong here, so what's going wrong?

```
$title = 'test';
$test1 = 'test';
$test2 = 'test';

$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_input'    => array(
        '_test1'    => $test1,
        '_test2'    => $test2,
    ),
);

wp_insert_post( $new_post );
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the meta to see if it was added or not? Assign wp_insert_post to a variable and var_dump it and see what's returned.

Comment: I am looking in the database, I'm not in front of my computer right now but IDs expect to get the post ID as it does insert it, just no post meta

Comment: Looking in the wp_postmeta table right?

Comment: Yep in the post meta table